# Ho can I recreate all my running containers in a single shot?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have multiple containers which are running. I changed the docker log driver and want all my running containers to start using the new configuration. In docker's documentation, they said all containers must be recreated. I keep my applications in multiple folders, so I can't recreate them with a single command.
I have to go to each of the following folders one by one:

```
/home/docker/folder1 
/home/docker/folder2 
/home/docker/folder3
```

Then run the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose down 
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d
```

Is there any workaround?

I tried:

```
# /usr/local/bin/docker-compose down 
ERROR: 
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list all running container and "give" them to `docker container restart`. For example:

```bash
docker container restart $(docker container ls --quiet)
```

If you only want to do it for container created by compose, use can filter by label

```bash
docker container restart \
  $(docker container ls --quiet --filter label=com.docker.compose.project)
```

Alternatively, you can search for all compose files, and do something with them, for more advanced commands. Maybe this is required, if restart does not suffice.

```bash
find /home/docker -name docker-compose.yaml -type f \
| while read -r f; do 
  docker compose --file "$f" up --force-recreate -d
done
```

Or with xargs

```bash
find /home/docker -name docker-compose.yaml -type f \
| xargs --no-run-if-empty -I{} docker compose --file {} up --force-recreate -d
```

If you have `jq` installed, you could get the path to the compose files more reliably by using `docker compose ls` with the JSON formatted output

```bash
docker compose ls --format json \
  | jq -rc 'map(.ConfigFiles) | .[]' \
  | xargs -r -I{} docker compose -f {} up --force-recreate -d
```

If you want to take care of the name as well, you need to use that from the output too.

```bash
docker compose ls --format json \
  | jq -c '.[]' | while read -r config; do 
  docker compose \
    -p "$(echo "$config" | jq -r '.Name')" \
    -f "$(echo "$config" | jq -r '.ConfigFiles')" \
    up --force-recreate -d
done
```

This is still not 100% solid since you may have used more than 1 config file. In that case, you can replace the commas with colons in the ConfigFiles and set the env variable `COMPOSE_FILE`

```bash
docker compose ls --format json \
  | jq -c '.[]' | while read -r config; do 
  COMPOSE_FILE="$(echo "$config" | jq -r '.ConfigFiles' | tr -s , :)" \
   docker compose \
    -p "$(echo "$config" | jq -r '.Name')" \
    up --force-recreate -d
done
```

There is still one problem that you can't overcome that way, if you have used specific profiles, you have no way of knowing which ones. So hopefully `docker container restart` is enough, as it would avoid most issues related to finding compose files and using compose.